# Algebra of limits are f(x)+g(x) tends to infinity as x tends to infinity.

Tags: limits

If you have two function both tending to infinity as x tend to infinity. How can you prove the addition algebra of limits?
My definition for a function tending to infinity as x tends to infinity, is give A>0 there exists a real number K such that f(x)>A whenever x>k.
Using this in the prove would both of the function >A and would x> k for both or do you change the variables?

Comment: You should consider choosing maximum of k of two functions f and g.

Comment: @user291957 would I create B>0 for the g(x)? Then say k=max(A,B)

Comment: I think you got the answer Below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A>0$. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ then there's $K>0$ such that

$$f(x)>A\quad\text{whenever}\; x\ge K$$
and since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)=+\infty$ then there's $K'>0$ such that 
$$g(x)>1\quad\text{whenever}\; x\ge K'$$
so if $x\ge K''=\max(K,K')$ then
$$f(x)+g(x)> A+1>A$$
so we get:

$$\text{for given}\; A>0\;\exists K''>0\;\text{such that}\; f(x)+g(x)>A\quad\text{whenever}\; x\ge K''$$
which means
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)+g(x)=+\infty$$

Comment: Why do you not use 2A in the third line from the bottom? @samibenromdhame

Comment: Yes if you want you can use $2A$ but it isn't necessary.